# Populate Column with Data from One Cell in CSV?

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, csv

I am using SQL Server 2012. I have a number of CSV files with historical purchase data from a client's candy store. At the top of every file, there is a date for the purchase data in the file, followed by the column headers. What I want to do is populate a column with the name "PurchaseDate", then add the date of the purchase (the date at the top of the file) into that column till the end of the file, followed by importing the file. I found how to import CSV files in T-SQL [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/06/20/sql-server-importing-csv-file-into-database-sql-in-sixty-seconds-018-video/), but have otherwise been unable to find the answer to this problem. The sheer number of files (50-60) prevents me from effectively importing the data manually. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing the tables is going to be the most tedious part. Then you can just run this on each of them.

```
CREATE TABLE ImportedCsv (
  [01/21/2013] nvarchar(max),
  [Column 1] nvarchar(max),
  [Column 2] nvarchar(max)
);

ALTER TABLE ImportedCsv ADD PurchaseDate DATETIME;

DECLARE
  @PurchaseDate nvarchar(max)

SELECT TOP 1
  @PurchaseDate = CAST(column_name as nvarchar(max))
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'ImportedCsv'
ORDER BY ordinal_position

UPDATE ImportedCsv SET PurchaseDate = CAST(@PurchaseDate as datetime)
```